# Retrieving page with anchor AJAX not working in IE

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

We released a site a couple of weeks ago and we are now getting complains that the website doesn't work in Internet Explorer 6-10.

Im using jQuery version: 1.11.0

We are running AJAX to load each page with an anchor. For example. www.site.com/#page2

Im trying to debug the code and see where it fails but I have no idea what is wrong.

The problem people are having is simple, the page doesn't load. All other code except the page call is working. So basically the page is empty.

This is a simplified version of the code:

```
function retrieve_page(link, lang){

    event.preventDefault();

    var id = link;

    if(id){

        document.location = "#"+id;

    } else {

        document.location = "#hem";

    }

    if(window.location.hash.substring(1) != "undefined") {

        var page = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    } else {

        var page = "hem";

    }

    var content;

    var request = $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax/retriever.php",
        data: { page:page },
        success: function(data) {

            content = data;

        }

    });

    request.done( function () {

        $('#page').html(content);

    });


}
```

and this is the `ajax/retriever.php` file

```
<?php

    $page = $_GET["page"];
    $path = "../pages/".$page.".php";
    $config = "../core/config.php";

    if(!file_exists($path)){

        require_once $config;

        echo "<div id='no_page'><h1 style='display: block'>".$lang["ERROR"]."</h1><a href='index.php'><h2>".$lang["ERROR_RETURN"]."</h2></a></div>";
        exit;

    } else {

        require_once $config;
        require_once $path;
        exit;

    }

?>
```

The AJAX function call is example:

```
<a onclick="retrieve_page('page1', 'sv')">Page1</a>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using 1.xx or 2.xx as version 2 doesn't support earlier versions of IE

Comment: Forgot to mention that. Im using 1.11.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't see how i missed it. Well i solved the issue with simply removing `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: well, sometimes you have to tell your story to actually see it.